# How do I include mysql.h and my_global.h into the Makefile.am?

Tags: mysql, c, autotools, automake

I'm trying to create a C program that can communicate with MySQL database via these two header files:

```
mysql.h 
my_global.h
```

MySQL comes with mysql_config script that you can execute to find out where the include files and library files reside in the system. I was wondering how would you define it in the Makefile.am?

I currently have the following:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = db    
db_SOURCES = db.c db.h                                            
db_CFLAGS = -Wall `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search for `mysql_config` in `configure.ac` using the [AX_WITH_PROG](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_with_prog.html) macro:

```
AX_WITH_PROG([MYSQL_CONFIG], [mysql_config], [AC_MSG_ERROR(mysql_config is required to build)])
```

so your users will be able to point the `MYSQL_CONFIG` environment variable at the program should it be installed in an unexpected location. And if the users haven't installed it, they will get a nice error message which alerts them to that fact *before* attempting to build.

I'd probably set up the cflags, cppflags, and libs in `configure.ac` as well, since they shouldn't change after `configure` is run:

```
MYSQL_CONFIG_CFLAGS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --cflags`
MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --include`
MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --libs`
AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS])
```

and put them in place in `Makefile.am`

```
db_CFLAGS = -Wall $(MYSQL_CONFIG_CFLAGS)
db_CPPFLAGS=$(MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS)
db_LDADD=$(MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS)
```

If all you need is the header files, you probably won't need to set up the cflags variable.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar:
in the configure.ac:

```
AC_DEFUN([CHECK_MYSQL_LIB],
[
AC_CHECK_PROGS(
    MYSQL_CONFIG,
    mysql_config
)

  #In case it fails to find pthread then exit configure 
  if test "x${MYSQL_CONFIG}" != xmysql_config; then
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    echo " The mysql library and header file is      "
    echo " required to build this project. Stopping "
    echo " Check 'config.log' for more information. "
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    (exit 1); exit 1;
  else
    MYSQL_CONFIG_CFLAGS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --cflags`
    MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --include`
    MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS=`$MYSQL_CONFIG --libs`
    AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_CFLAGS])
    AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS])
    AC_SUBST([MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS])
  fi
])
```

And in the Makefile.am:

```
db_CPPFLAGS=$(MYSQL_CONFIG_CPPFLAGS)
db_LDFLAGS=$(MYSQL_CONFIG_LIBS)
```

Note that is better to add in the **LDFLAGS** instead of **LDADD**.