# How to include he C++ mysql library in configure and makefile.am?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using the auto-tools for compiling and executing the code. What is procedure for adding C++ mysql library in configure and makefile.am. I want to add the mysql library files in configure file and makefile.am.

[How do I include mysql.h and my_global.h into the Makefile.am?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799185/how-do-i-include-mysql-h-and-my-global-h-into-the-makefile-am) this didn't helped me.

This is the Error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()", referenced from:

```
  makeConnection()
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[2]: *** [quaestord] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [AX_LIB_MYSQL](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_lib_mysql.html) in your `configure.ac` like this:

**configure.ac**

```
AX_LIB_MYSQL([5.0])
```

If MySql is found (minimum version `5.0`) you can use these variables in your `Automake.am`:

```
HAVE_MYSQL
MYSQL_CFLAGS
MYSQL_LDFLAGS
MYSQL_VERSION
```

Something like:

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = my_database_program

my_database_program_SOURCES = my_database_program.cpp

my_database_program_CXXFLAGS = $(MYSQL_CFLAGS)
my_database_program_LDFLAGS  = $(MYSQL_LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_get_driver_instance", referenced from:
      makeConnection() 
How to resolve this?

Comment: @HasnatAhmed Have you installed the mysql development libraries?

Comment: yes I have installed the mysql libraries in my laptop? but how can we install it using c++ auto tools?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the `x86_64` version and not the `i686` version?

Comment: Also you need the connector development libraries, the package names of development libraries usually end in `-devel` or `-dev` (they are usually seperate from the library itself).

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()", referenced from:
      makeConnection()
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [quaestord] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1